# ModelSim DUT not showing up in sim panel

Tags: vhdl, fpga, modelsim, quartus

I'm working on a project with a friend. Below is a screenshot of **my** ModelSim panel when I run an RTL simulation. You can see that the **DUT shows up** and I'm able to expand it and add waves to the waveform diagram.

When **he** runs the same testbench the same way though, the **DUT does not show up** in the sim panel and so he's not able to verify if the testbench is working or not.

Does anyone know why this happens or how he can fix this problem?

[image: Screenshot of ModelSIM]

Comment: Perhaps DUT is unbound because his compilation script differs or he's missing the sources for DUT? Perhaps he isn't looking at the instance hierarchy window? There's very little information for us to go off of here. Do any warnings or errors appear during elaboration (the start of simulation)?

Answer (score 0):

We figured out that the reason it wasn't showing up is because he hadn't compiled the code before runnnig the testbench simulation. I can't speak as to how or why that fixed it, but doing a full compilation fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I too having same problem. But i found the solution that after compilation and simulation "Start Simulation" window will occur. In that in the "Optimization" Click on "Optimization Options" and select "Apply full Visibility to all Modules (full debug mode)" and click ok. Now DUT file will appear.

Thanks